sudo apt - get update not working
Conflicting values set for option Signed-By regarding source https://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/yannubuntu/boot-repair/ubuntu/ noble: /etc/apt/keyrings/boot-repair.gpg

Welcome to AskUbuntu. Please see https://askubuntu.com/help/how-to-ask

This question is similar to: "Conflicting values set for option Signed-By regarding source". If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.
